# No VR (Virtual Reality) for Windows Phone yet? Any possibility in near future?

Tags: windows-phone, virtual-reality

No **VR (Virtual Reality)** for ***Windows Phone*** yet? Any possibility in near future?

WP severely lacks here. When can we (Windows Phone users) expect it?

Anyone having an idea can shed some light.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Vamshi, welcome to stack exchange. Stack Overflow is not designed to answer such vague questions. It's rather about more technical issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but Windows Phone is practically dead. It could work as a Cardboard device, but you would need something cross platform to render the view. Some [web apps](http://monkeys.hypernom.com/) could work, but mobile IE video support is lacking so don't expect any video player. On a side note, I'm an author of a 360 video web player, and have seen zero pressure to support WP (panoramas work out of the box, though).